# Import certificate into VisualSVN Server

Tags: svn, certificate, visualsvn, visualsvn-server

Is it possible to import the valid certificate of the Windows Server, where VisualSVN is installed, into VisualSVN?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### Read the article [KB134: Configuring SSL Certificates for VisualSVN Server](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00134/).

**UPDATE:** Importing certificates in pfx format implemented VisualSVN Server 2.6:
https://www.visualsvn.com/server/changes/2.6/

---

Yes, it's possible. Please consider the following steps:

1. Export certificate and private key to pfx format
2. Convert certificate and private key to PEM format using following command:
   `"%VISUALSVN_SERVER%\bin\openssl" pkcs12 -in mycert.pfx -out mycert.pem -nodes`
3. Start **VisualSVN Server Manager**.
4. Open properties for root node.
5. Click **Change certificate** button on **Certificate** property page.
6. Click **Import signed certificate** option.
7. Browse to PEM encoded certificate and private key.
8. Click **Finish** and then **Apply**.