# How to generate certificate file for svn server, and import

Tags: eclipse, openssl, repository, svn-server

I would like to use svn server to share source code in a repository among computers on a home network.  I have svnserver and openssl installed on the computer with the repository.  Can someone give me step by step instructions on generating a certificate, incorporating into svnserver, putting the certificate on the other computers, and accessing the repository from eclipse.

The computers are running versions of windows.

I'm following the steps at 
http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/show/1469-how-to-become-your-own-certificate-authority-and-secure-spiceworks

and have put the following commands into a script file for cygwin

```
# Generate CA root certificate
openssl req -new -x509 -extensions v3_ca \ 
   -keyout cakey.pem -out cacert.pem -days 3650

# Move to /etc/ssl
mv cakey.pem /etc/ssl/private 
mv cacert.pem /etc/ssl/certs.

# Generate Secure and Insecure Keys
openssl genrsa -des3 -out server.key 2048
openssl rsa -in server.key -out server.key.insecure 
mv server.key server.key.secure 
mv server.key.insecure server.key
```

At this point, I think I copy the contents of server.key and server.key.insecure into the file 
C:\Program Files (x86)\VisualSVN Server\certs\server.pem

but, I'm not sure about that.  Also, what file do I copy to the other computers and how to connect eclipse to the repository.

Also, is there an easier way to do this besides using svnserver, since all the machines are on the same home network, and they are running versions of windows?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356997/import-certificate-into-visualsvn-server

Comment: That answer is addressing the question of converting an existing certificate for Windows Server to SVN Server, which appears to be converting from pkcs12 format to pem format.  My questions are 1) how to create the certificate, 2) how to get it in svn server (the referenced question addresses this), 3) where to put the certificate on the remote machines, and 4) how to get the certificate into eclipse to allows accessing the server.  I think part of the problem is the way I'm creating the certificate, and not specifying the server address, but I'm not sure...

Comment: I'm not sure if the problem is with the certificate.  I reworded the problem and submitted as question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17383761/access-visualsvn-server-from-eclipse

Comment: See site http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17383761/access-visualsvn-server-from-eclipse/17383959#17383959