# Access visualsvn server from eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, visualsvn-server

When I enter the url for the server into a browser (Chrome, Firefox) I can access the repository if I accept the security exception.

When I enter the url into svn repository location in eclipse, along with the user name and password, I get an error occured while accessing the repository entry.

The error from eclipse is SVN: 0x00400006: Validate Repository Location operation finished with error: Selected SVN connector library is not available or cannot be loaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The instructions from this site worked

http://www.polarion.com/products/svn/subversive/download.php

In eclipse, go to help/install new software

Add the site

http://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/3.0/juno-site/

Install the svn connectors and svnkit.

Now, I can reach the server repository from eclipse.  It may be helpful to use New / project from repository.